# Listar duas tabelas distintas e filtrar por data MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Meu problema é que eu preciso listar valores de duas tabelas distintas, e estou utilizando um filtro para adicionar condições na query.
Por exemplo:

```
if(!empty($mes_especifico)) {
   $sql .= "AND YEAR(d.data_pagamento) = :ano AND MONTH(d.data_pagamento) = :mes ";
   $insertData[":ano"] = $ano;
   $insertData[":mes"] = $mes;
}
```

Eu queria saber como unir na mesma query e listar as tabelas e ordenar pelo número de parcelas.

Tabelas: https://pastebin.com/rexcXTKw

Separadas:

```
SELECT FORMAT(r.valor_receita,2,'de_DE') AS valor_receita,
       DATE_FORMAT(r.data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
       r.recebido,
       DATE_FORMAT(r.data_recebimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_recebimento,
       r.tipo_repeticao,
       r.parcelas,
       r.numero_parcela,
       r.recorrente,
       r.observacoes,
       tr.tipo_receita,
       re.tipo_recebimento
FROM receitas AS r
INNER JOIN tipo_receita AS tr ON r.id_tipo_receita = tr.id_tipo_receita
INNER JOIN tipo_recebimento AS re ON r.id_tipo_recebimento = re.id_tipo_recebimento
WHERE r.id_usuario = 1;

SELECT FORMAT(d.valor_despesa,2,'de_DE') AS valor_despesa,
       DATE_FORMAT(d.data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
       d.pago,
       DATE_FORMAT(d.data_pagamento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_pagamento,
       d.importante,
       d.tipo_repeticao,
       d.parcelas,
       d.numero_parcela,
       d.recorrente,
       d.observacoes,
       td.tipo_despesa,
       c.nome_categoria,
       tp.tipo_pagamento
FROM despesas AS d
INNER JOIN tipo_despesa AS td ON d.id_tipo_despesa = td.id_tipo_despesa
INNER JOIN tipo_pagamento AS tp ON d.id_tipo_pagamento = tp.id_tipo_pagamento
INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON td.id_categoria = c.id_categoria
WHERE d.id_usuario = 1;
```

Comment: no seu código pastebin.com/rexcXTKw , a coluna `tipo_despesa` é do tipo `varchar`, e na tabela de despesas, `id_tipo_despesa` é `INT`, a `FK` não vai funcionar

Comment: Na tabela tipo_despesa existem as colunas id_tipo_despesa e tipo_despesa. Um é INT e outro VARCHAR

Comment: tentei colocar seu código no SQLFiddle, e deu erro, possívelmente porque o nome de uma coluna está igual ao nome de uma tabela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se todas as colunas forem do mesmo tipo, basta usar o `UNION`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(r.valor_receita,2,'de_DE') AS valor_receita,
       DATE_FORMAT(r.data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
       r.recebido,
       DATE_FORMAT(r.data_recebimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_recebimento,
       null as importante,
       r.tipo_repeticao,
       r.parcelas,
       r.numero_parcela,
       r.recorrente,
       r.observacoes,
       tr.tipo_receita,
       null as categoria,
       re.tipo_recebimento
FROM receitas AS r
INNER JOIN tipo_receita AS tr ON r.id_tipo_receita = tr.id_tipo_receita
INNER JOIN tipo_recebimento AS re ON r.id_tipo_recebimento = re.id_tipo_recebimento
WHERE r.id_usuario = 1

UNION 

SELECT FORMAT(d.valor_despesa,2,'de_DE') AS valor_despesa,
       DATE_FORMAT(d.data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
       d.pago,
       DATE_FORMAT(d.data_pagamento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_pagamento,
       d.importante,
       d.tipo_repeticao,
       d.parcelas,
       d.numero_parcela,
       d.recorrente,
       d.observacoes,
       td.tipo_despesa,
       c.nome_categoria,
       tp.tipo_pagamento
FROM despesas AS d
INNER JOIN tipo_despesa AS td ON d.id_tipo_despesa = td.id_tipo_despesa
INNER JOIN tipo_pagamento AS tp ON d.id_tipo_pagamento = tp.id_tipo_pagamento
INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON td.id_categoria = c.id_categoria
WHERE d.id_usuario = 1;
```

Obs. Utilize null para acertar as colunas que faltam na outra tabela, assim consegue executar o comando.

Se houver conflito de tipos, você pode converter os valores.

Comment: Já tentei desta forma, mas retorna o seguinte: Os comandos SELECT usados têm diferente número de colunas

Comment: adicionei mais informação, veja

Comment: Funcionou por parte... o filtro não está funcionando bem.

Comment: Por exemplo... quando eu filtro pra listar somente tipo de despesa ou receita específico, numa data específica

Comment: você vai ter que adicionar o comando `"AND YEAR(d.data_pagamento) = :ano AND MONTH(d.data_pagamento) = :mes "` na primeira parte da query também

Comment: Tentei assim: https://pastebin.com/QukRKL4B
Mas sem o resultado realmente esperado...

Comment: o que deu errado ? tente utilizar o SQLFiddle

Comment: A mesma coisa que o código do amigo acima... testa adicionar o seguinte: `AND tipo_despesa = 'Água'` no WHERE de despesas... Eu preciso que retorne somente as despesas de água, ignorando os tipos de receita, a não ser que fosse informado no filtro também.

Answer (score 2):

A solução já apresentada está certa, você deverá usar o UNION mesmo, equiparando os tipos dos campos em ambos os `SELECTs`, considerar que os campos existam em ambos "SELECTs", quando não existe, você os cria como sendo "NULL" e dá o nome pra ele com o "AS".
Por outro lado, é bom você dar o nome identico aos campos pra que sejam reconhecidos, assim você não terá o problema que diz ter.
Com base nisto, remodelei seu script conforme segue:

```
SELECT valor,
       data_vencimento,
       estatus,
       data_movimento,
       importante,
       tipo_repeticao,
       parcelas,
       num_parcelas,
       recorrente,
       observacoes,
       tipo_origem,
       categoria,
       tipo_movto,
       identifica_origem
  FROM (
        SELECT FORMAT(r.valor_receita,2,'de_DE') AS valor,
               DATE_FORMAT(r.data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
               r.recebido as estatus,
               DATE_FORMAT(r.data_recebimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_movimento,
               NULL as importante,
               r.tipo_repeticao as tipo_repeticao,
               r.parcelas as parcelas,
               r.numero_parcela as num_parcelas,
               r.recorrente as recorrente,
               r.observacoes as observacoes,
               tr.tipo_receita as tipo_origem,
               NULL as categoria,
               re.tipo_recebimento as tipo_movto,
               'Receita' AS identifica_origem
          FROM receitas AS r
               INNER JOIN tipo_receita AS tr ON (r.id_tipo_receita = tr.id_tipo_receita)
               INNER JOIN tipo_recebimento AS re ON (r.id_tipo_recebimento = re.id_tipo_recebimento)
        WHERE r.id_usuario = 1
        UNION 
        SELECT FORMAT(d.valor_despesa,2,'de_DE') AS valor,
               DATE_FORMAT(d.data_vencimento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_vencimento,
               d.pago AS estatus,
               DATE_FORMAT(d.data_pagamento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_movimento
               d.importante AS importante,
               d.tipo_repeticao as tipo_repeticao,
               d.parcelas as parcelas,
               d.numero_parcela as num_parcelas,
               d.recorrente  as recorrente,
               d.observacoes as observacoes,
               td.tipo_despesa as tipo_origem,
               c.nome_categoria as categoria,
               tp.tipo_pagamento as tipo_movto,
               'Despesa' AS identifica_origem
          FROM despesas AS d
               INNER JOIN tipo_despesa AS td ON (d.id_tipo_despesa = td.id_tipo_despesa)
               INNER JOIN tipo_pagamento AS tp ON (d.id_tipo_pagamento = tp.id_tipo_pagamento)
               INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON (td.id_categoria = c.id_categoria)
         WHERE d.id_usuario = 1
        ) AS origem
       ) AS origem
 WHERE (tipo_origem = 'Água')
 ORDER BY data_movimento
```

Veja que os `SELECTs` eu os deixei entre parêntesis, como sendo o `FROM` do `SELECT` principal, o qual de o nome de `Origem`, partindo daí, posso filtrar, ordenar, em fim, tratar o resulta da `UNION` como bem entender, como um `select` normal.
O código pode parecer longo, mas vale perder um tempinho e deixa-lo bonito, assim, se necessário, ficará mais fácil o entendimento e a manutenção posteriori.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... bom.. está quase lá.. só que faz o seguinte.. testa adicionar o seguinte: `AND tipo_despesa = 'Água'` no WHERE de despesas... Eu preciso que retorne somente as despesas de água, ignorando os tipos de receita, a não ser que fosse informado no filtro também.

Comment: coloca esse where `tipo_despesa = 'Agua'` depois do `as origem` e antes do `ORDER BY data_movimento`, e junto dele, filtre pela coluna `identifica_origem` também, pegando somente da tabela `despesa`

Comment: Opa... acho que agora vai em... vou fazer mais alguns testes e depois retorno aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: Eduardo, alterei o exemplo conforme a dica do Rovvann, veja como ficou.
Minha dica, ao invés de deixar a pesquisa fixa em 'Água', utilize parâmetro, assim você usará o mesmo script para pesquisar qualquer despesa e ou receita; outra coisa, procure usar o TRIM e LIKE, podem ajudar mais, pois " Água" (com espaço a esquerda, "Água" (sem espaço) e "Água " (com espaço a direita), são diferentes.